# SSRS create report with given Guid as Identifier

Tags: reporting-services

I'm calling CreateReport method on ReportingService web service to create a report on the server. I was wondering if there is a way to give this newly created report a Guid I want for the ItemID in the Catalog table?

Answer (score 1):

No: it's an internal value. You'll never use it anywhere else and relying on the internals of the RS database is not a good idea anyway...